# Google sheets and long numbers

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to create a spreadsheet using Google Sheets.
One of the columns is for longitude values.
Another column is for lattitude values.

However, when I paste either longitude or latitude values into fields, the numeric strings are truncated.

Obviously sheets doesn't take long strings by default.

How can I configure Google Sheets to accept long numeric strings?

Answer (score 1):

you can format it as **Plain text** and when you need to do math with it you just multiply the text string by 1 co convert it into a numeric value

[image]